# Why does MXLinux/Linux become slow after a while of using it?

Tags: mx-linux

Eventually when I'm using Linux this becomes very slow after a while and it prevents me from opening new applications so I have to reboot the system because the **swap usage** exceeds **2.5gb**

Comment: I've translated your question to English. I'm not native English speaker (I also speak spanish) so I might have some mistakes in the grammar. Nevertheless what I've translated should describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason they complain that linux is slow is the exchange. In windows sharing is so well optimized that you almost don't notice when the system uses it. On the other hand, in linux, the exchange causes slowness.

This is to be improved in the next project called "le9"
https://www.muylinux.com/2021/07/14/le9-poca-ram-linux/

In my case I use mxlinux with cinnamon and I discovered that by switching to the antix kernel, for some reason the consumption of the apps has gone down. I even run vscode, chrome, evernote, postman and an app to translate in only 6gb of ram and swap is managed better than other kernels like licuorix.

This is the kernel version I use:

```
Linux JuanDavid 5.10.142-antix.2-amd64-smp #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 9 21:15:01 EEST 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And this is the swap usage configuration in /etc/sysctl.conf

```
vm.swappiness = 15
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 200
vm.dirty_ratio = 3
vm.page-cluster=3
vm.watermark_scale_factor = 150
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

The **vm.watermark_scale_factor** property determines the aggressiveness of kswapd, the daemon that handles the swapping. By setting it to this value I have verified that the slowness decreases when paging from ram to disk begins.

Also as an alternative is the liquorix kernel that claims to have an improvement of chromeOS in the use of swap. I recommend the liquorix 5.14 series and liquorix 6.0.0-11.2.

You can download it from here: https://mxrepo.com/mx/repo/pool/ahs/l/linux-liquorix/

With liquorix the use of swap is good but, when it reaches 3gb of swap used, the system becomes very slow. For this reason I prefer the antix kernel, because it is very well patched and prioritizes the use of ram over swap.

For the sample of a button I can use chrome, vscode (which is heavy because it is done in electron and opens the node process), evernote, whatsie, postman and crow translate to translate. All this in a machine with 6gb of ram with cinnamon.

Before, it was very slow and with liquorix it worked fine, but I had to restart after hours due to the increase in swap usage.

Well I hope this is helpful.